# Laravel 5 Routing ALL routes

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, routes, frameworks

I am new to laravel, and im trying to get redirect all incoming requests from `/example` to  `exampleController@index` I am using this route

```
 Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/example/{any}', ['uses' =>'exampleController@index'])->where('any', '.*');
```

Everything works fine with `/example/any/any/any`, but I am getting `No input file specified.` error when i try `/example/any/any/any.php` Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: NGIX will forward requests to .php files to the PHP file handler without checking if the file exists. In apache this is usually resolved using mod_rewrite I'm guessing NGIX has something similar. Check http://nginxlibrary.com/resolving-no-input-file-specified-error/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, i managed to do what i wanted by changing my NGINX config. Simply added this `try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` Now it works as expected.

Comment: It may help others if you answered your own question with the  solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Route::match` is only used to match multiple `HTTP Verbs` to a route.

As far as I know you can't achieve what you want, and there is no point to do this.

What you may need is `Route::resource` check the docs

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working by editing NGINX config file. In my situation im using laravel 5 homestead with default configuration. Config file is located `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/homestead.app`. Add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` right after `location ~ \.php$`. Should look similar to this

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to why, but you can use Route::group with a prefix as such

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'example'], function() {
    Route::get('action/{id}', 'ExampleController@getAction');
});
```

Going to http://yoursite.com/example/action/111 will use the getAction method in the ExampleController.

```php
public function getAction($id) {
    // do something with Example with this $id
}
```

Comment: I am working on "smart" proxy server, so i want that all incoming requests to `application.com/proxy/{method}/{method}?{parameters}` would use same method `ProxyController@index`. Any way.. Extension problem fixed, thanks for comments. Cheers